# Though undefined in console, javascript variable within setInterval shows its value on alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascript snippet :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON('notif.php', function(data) {
            my_var = '123';
        });
        alert("my var =" + my_var);
    }, 2000);

});    
</script>
```

in chrome and FF console, my_var shows to be undefined, but its value is shown on the alertbox. if undefined , then how is its val

What is the explanation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getJSON in jquery is by default `asynch` call so the `alert("my var =" + my_var);` will be executed without waiting for the response of the ajax call.

move the alert inside callback function like

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('notif.php', function(data) {
        my_var = '123';
        alert("my var =" + my_var);
    });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable scope is the topic You are looking for.

The variable my_var exists only in the scope of the closure called by ajax success.

If You would define the my_var on a higher level like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var my_var;
...
```

You could see it in Your console.

Comment: nope ... it's not the scope. Without the "var" it will be global anyway. It's about asynchronous tasks. my_var only becomes defined after the request finished

Comment: You are right. If there would be var my_var in the ajax, that would be my case...

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript variable declaration:**

```
var foo; //sets foo to undefined
console.log(foo) //-> undefined

foo = "bar" //sets foo's value to "bar"
console.log(foo) //-> "bar"

var foo = "bar"; //sets foo to undefined initially, then changes it's value to "bar"
console.log(foo) //-> "bar"
```

**So in your case:**

`my_var` is always going to have a value of `undefined` until its assigned a different value.